# XFCE terminal opens on host machine

Tags: gnome-terminal, debian, xfce4-terminal

I'm currently remote connecting from my windows machine to my pc on ubuntu. Whenever I try to open terminal in xfce, it opens instead on the host machine, therefore i cannot access the terminal from xfce. All the other applications work on xfce and do not open a new window on the host device. How to i fix it so i can access terminal from xfce? I've tried using both GNOME and Debian X, neither of which works

Comment: You haven't given any releases of OS, in fact with mention & tagging of debian it's somewhat confusing whether you are talking about a Ubuntu release, debian or it appears both.  Did the Xubuntu shortcut work?  (*your release info may allow me to be less vague*)

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this.Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Sorry for the confusion description, what i meant was that i tried using both terminal emulators, and neither worked. Assuming you mean the shortcut for terminal on xfce, it also opens a new terminal window on the host

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue resolved by uninstalling xfce-terminal and reinstalling in ubuntu 19.10. In my case the terminal woul

```
sudo apt remove xfce4-terminal
sudo apt install xfce4-terminal
```